# Using Sed to replace a string with another string?

Tags: unix, command-line, sed

I have tried this:

```
sed -i 's/'Twas/It certainly was/g' *.txt
```

any suggestions??

Comment: I think I know what's wrong, but in the future, please describe what happened, as well as what you expected to happen, when asking a question like this.  That makes it much easier for people to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes

```
sed -i "s/'Twas/It certainly was/g" *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe in `'Twas` is being interpreted as a close quote (by the shell, not sed), and then the subsequent single quote after `/g` is being interpreted as an *open* quote, which cheerfully gobbles all the way to the end of the script (or the command prompt, and then you get the mysterious `>` that means the shell thinks there's more to come).  For this situation,

```
sed -i "s/'Twas/It certainly was/g" *.txt
```

should work; however, shell double-quoted strings do a lot of stuff you don't usually want with sed programs.  If there were any regexp metacharacters at all in there I'd do instead

```
sed -i 's/'\''Twas/It certainly was/g' *.txt
```

Comment: oh ok how about if i wanted to change "the" or "The" with "a" or "A" (preserving the capitalization of the original)? If that makes sense...

Comment: You can't do that easily with `sed` because it doesn't support word-boundary matches.  But `perl -pi~ -e 's/\bthe\b/a/g; s/\bThe\b/A/g'` will do it.  I don't know any clever way to do both replacements with one regexp, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: Ok ill post another post But i mean i might just use perl thanks for all the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using following

grep -rl "Old string" directoryPath | xargs sed -i 's/oldString/new String/g'

Example :

grep -rl 10.113.1.115 matchdir | xargs sed -i 's/10.113.1.115/10.113.1.65/g'