# Replacing text with apostrophe text via sed in applescript

Tags: sed, applescript, replace

I have an applescript to find and replace a number of strings. I ran in the problem of having a replacement string which contained & some time ago, but could get around it by putting \& in the replacement property list. However an apostrophe seems to be far more annoying.

Using a single apostrophe just gets ignored (replacement doesn't contain it), using \' gives a syntax error (Expected “"” but found unknown token.) and using \' gets ignored again. (You can keep doing that btw, even number gets ignored uneven gets syntax error)

I tried replacing the apostrophe in the actual sed command with double quotes (sed "s…" instead of sed 's…'), which works in the command line, but gives a syntax error in the script (Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.)

The single quotes mess with the shell, the double quotes with applescript.

I also tried '\'' as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002981/using-sed-to-replace-a-string-with-another-string) and '"'"' from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/sed-matching-an-apostrophe-439625/).

Basic script to get the type of errors:

```
set findList to "Thats.nice"
set replaceList to "That's nice"
set fileName to "Thats.nice.whatever"
set resultFile to do shell script "echo " & fileName & " | sed 's/" & findList & "/" & replaceList & " /'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set findList to "Thats.nice"
set replaceList to "That's nice"
set fileName to "Thats.nice.whatever"
set resultFile to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of fileName & " | sed \"s/Thats.nice/That\\'s nice/\""
```

or to stick to your example:

```
set findList to "Thats.nice"
set replaceList to "That's nice"

set fileName to "Thats.nice.whatever"
set resultFile to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of fileName & " | sed \"s/" & findList & "/" & replaceList & "/\""
```

### Explanation:

The sed statement is usually enclosed by single quotes like this:

```
set myText to "Hello"
set xxx to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myText & " | sed 's/ello/i/'"
```

However, in this example you could have exluded the single quotes altogether.

```
set myText to "Hello"
set xxx to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myText & " | sed s/ello/i/"
```

The unquoted sed statement will break down as soon a space is included.

```
set myText to "Hello"
set xxx to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myText & " | sed s/ello/i there/"
--> error "sed: 1: \"s/ello/i\": unterminated substitute in regular expression" number 1
```

Since you can't include an apostrophe within a single quoted statement (even if you escape it), you can enclose the sed statement in double quotes like this:

```
set myText to "Johns script"
set xxx to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myText & " | sed \"s/ns/n's/\""
```

EDIT
Lauri Ranta makes a good point that if your find or replace string contains escaped double quotes my  answer won't work. Her solution is as follows:

```
set findList to "John's"
set replaceList to "\"Lauri's\""
set fileName to "John's script"
set resultFile to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of fileName & " | sed s/" & quoted form of findList & "/" & quoted form of replaceList & "/"
```

Comment: `echo '\t'` prints  literal tab when bash is invoked as sh, but `printf %s '\t'`, `shopt -u xpg_echo; echo '\t'`, or `<<< '\t'` doesn't. The patterns could be shell-escaped with `"sed s/" & quoted form of findList & "/" & quoted form of replaceList & "/"`.

Comment: Hi Lauri, I'm not sure I follow you. Can you give a find and replace example where my answer breaks?

Comment: `findList` and `replaceList` can't contain double quotes in the second code block. `myText` can't contain escape sequences like `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also use text item delimiters. You don't have to include `AppleScript's` in the default scope or set the property back if it isn't used later.

```
set input to "aasearch"
set text item delimiters to "search"
set ti to text items of input
set text item delimiters to "replace"
ti as text
```

There's no easy way to escape the search or replace patterns if they can contain something that would be interpreted by sed.

```
set input to "a[a"
set search to "[a"
set replace to "b"

do shell script "sed s/" & quoted form of search & "/" & quoted form of replace & "/g <<< " & quoted form of input
```

If you have to use regular expressions, scripting languages like Ruby have methods for creating patterns from strings.

```
set input to "aac"
set search to "(a+)"
set replace to "\\1b"

do shell script "ruby -KUe 'print STDIN.read.chomp.gsub(Regexp.new(ARGV[0]), ARGV[1])' " & quoted form of search & " " & quoted form of replace & " <<< " & quoted form of input without altering line endings
```